# PHP text box replace with variable

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a small customer database that allows me to send an email.
So what I would like to do is, click a link that opens a page with a big text box. 
Within this text box I'd get a preformatted HTML mail, that I can adapt if I want.
When I process the form text box I would like to search for all the variables that have been written in the textbox. (because besides plain HTML I would like to be able to use variables where I want within the email)
I want to be able to write the variable in my text box between `<< some_variable >>`
Then I would like the processing page to search for all text between `<< ** >>`.
And replace it with `$some_variable`.
(off course we would know the syntax off the variables up front)

So for example in the html form input box I would like to type this:

```
Hi <<First_Name>>,
You registered for course <<course_number>> <<course_title>>.
Total to pay <<Total_to_pay>>.
Thanks
```

but I would also want to be able to change the format whenever I want.
So example:

```
Hi <<First_Name>>,
Your course <course_number>> <<course_title>>, will start tomorrow.
Dont' be late.
```

Thanks

Comment: So? What is your problem, and how you tried to solve it?

Comment: So you are looking to create a html template using shortcodes where you feed it some information and it displays on the screen?  

How does it get this information from a php script or js?

You might want to look at http://mustache.github.io/ rather than implementing your own shortcode parser.

Comment: Just do `str_replace('<<some_variable>>',$some_variable,$template);`

Answer (score 0):

You can post or get the input value to session and set the session result as a first_name